# Sigmoidal potentials

Tags: potential, potential-energy

At first sight, elastic potentials $\sim  x^2$ and gravitation-like potentials $\sim 1/x$ look quite different and yield quite different behaviours of objects exposed to such potentials.

But if you cut them off, they start looking more similar:

[image]

Trying to smoothen the cut-offs and to approximate the two potentials even more leads somehow "naturally" to [sigmoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (e.g. $\sim x/\sqrt{1 + x^2}$):

[image]

I wonder which role sigmoidal potentials — as a generalized form of cut-off elastic and gravitation-like potentials which are mathematically very well understood — play in which areas of physics.

Searching for "[sigmoidal potential](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22sigmoidal%20potentials%22)" only yields 146 Google hits, "[sigmoid potential](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22sigmoid%20potentials%22)" yields 96 hits.

Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong term?

Comment: I personally don't know of any application that necessarily calls for such potentials. In the only examples I can find, a sigmoid is used specifically for its *qualitative* properties, i.e. it's a function that smoothly switches between two constants, rather than anything deeper. But even then, most would use a polynomial or something that is faster to compute than a sigmoid.